# Function to get difference in time as HOURS and MINUTES

Tags: acumatica

trying to get the time difference from when a sales order was created and when it was shipped. The only function I could get was DateDiff.

Is it possible to get the time in the format of “HOUR:MINUTE”?

=DateDiff( 'MINUTE',[SOShipment.ConfirmedDateTime],[SOOrder.CreatedDateTime])*-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use do a simple calculation to get your output like this in C#.

```
    DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime b = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).AddHours(6).AddMinutes(10);
    
    Console.WriteLine ("Created Date: " + a);
    Console.WriteLine ("Shipped Date: " + b);
    
    Console.WriteLine ("Days difference: " + (b - a).Days);
    Console.WriteLine ("Hours difference: " + (b - a).Hours);
    Console.WriteLine ("Minutes difference: " + (b - a).Minutes);
            
    Console.WriteLine ("Difference in hours and minutes: " + (((b - a).Days * 24) + (b - a).Hours) + ":" +  (b - a).Minutes);
```

Output of above code:

[image]